# render next page when scrolled to bottom

Tags: javascript, css

I have to create a parallax view for that I have taken three sections something like

```
<div>
//1
<section>
</section>

//2
<section>
</section>

//3
<section>
</section>
</div>
```

Now, everytime I scroll to bottom of the present section I want to automatically get scrolled to next section

I want the same functionality

https://codepen.io/country_runner/pen/mWXMgX

Just **there is a condition that every section is going to have a large amount of content** so, I want to have an overflow for every section and If I get to the bottom of that then I should get to the next page

As I can see in the styles of above example the 
`height:100vh` and `overflow:hidden` I changed it to `overflow: auto` and removed `height:100vh`

Also I tried to get the innerHeight of the section, and tried to track the current position of scroll using id, If I get to bottom It gets scrolled, but none works!

`document.getElementById('testi').getBoundingClientRect().bottom`
everytime I get different value, can please someone tell how to achieve this kind of functionality.

Comment: I would take time to go through all that to do what you asked, I suggest if you find no suggestions, you might mail the creator of the pen and describe your issue

Comment: Hello @Prottay, It will be so much helpful if you can help me with this, although I'll try to contact the creator of the pen, maybe that can work :)